# How to cast a object to IList<T> with unknown type T

Tags: c#, .net, windows, generics, casting

I have a `object[]` containig some values. I want to extract infomation out of it, but I fail at casting the second object in the array (a `WeakReference`) to a IList with T as the third value in the array.

Take a look at my code:

```
object[] vals = GetValues(); //vals[2] = WeakReference, vals[3] = Type of T, vals[4] = index in the list
IList<((Type)vals[3])> list = (IList<((Type)vals[3])>)(((WeakReference)vals[2]).Target); //This line does not even compile, seems like I'm doing something wrong..
object oo = list.ElementAt((int)vals[4]);
//Do something with oo...
```

Any suggestions how I can cast the Target of the WeakReference to a IList interface with T = vals[3] ?

Comment: Why don't you simply cast to a `IList` ?

Comment: because I need the `ElementAt` method, which only works with IList<T>

Comment: IList has the Item property, you can do `list[(int)vals[4]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's really strange that you are packing so much heterogeneous information into an *array*. Arrays are normally used to store elements of the *same* type. Why not encapsulate the data in a proper type?

But to answer the question as asked - in C# 4, you can use `dynamic`:

```
var target = ((dynamic)vals[2]).Target;

if(target != null)
{
    object oo = Enumerable.ElementAt(target, vals[4]);
    //Do something with oo...
}
```

(EDIT: If you want to minimize the use of `dynamic` here, cast to a `WeakReference` and leave the dynamic call to the end. This way, type-safety is 'maximized'.)

Otherwise, you can use reflection:

```
object target = ((WeakReference)vals[2]).Target;

if (target != null)
{
    object oo = target.GetType()
                      .GetProperty("Item")
                      .GetValue(target, new[] { vals[4] });
    //Do something with oo...
}
```

(EDIT: If the indexer could be explicitly implemented, you'll probably need to use the interface mappings.)

Comment: What's the advantage of casting to `dynamic` over `WeakReference` if you know that the object is a `WeakReference`?

Comment: I tried this, but `.GetProperty("Item")` returns `null` if the property is explicitly-implemented and therefore private.

Comment: @tvanfosson: Sure. Another `dynamic` cast will be needed later on  though.

Comment: This solution really looks overkill to me. Why would you need C# 4's 'dynamic' or reflection to get an object at a given position in a enumerable?

Comment: @Simon: Remember that the `IEnumerable` in this case is an `IList<T>`. By not using the indexer, we make the operation O(n) instead of O(1). Of course, if you extended your solution to try and find an indexer, and fall back on enumeration if not present, that would be fine. It would be come a more general version of `ElementAt` that works with any (non-generic) `IEnumerable`. I just picked the simpler solution in this case.

Comment: @Ani - Good point. I could add the test for IList (non generic). This would catch most actual IList<T> implementations. But still, I don't like the fact we rely on new C# constructs for this :-)

Answer (score 2):

It was already suggested that you could use `dynamic`, but it sounds like you are also supposed to check that the object has the specified type. I’ve also kept use of `dynamic` to a minimum:

```
object target = ((WeakReference) vals[2]).Target;

if (target == null)
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Target cannot be null.");

object result = Enumerable.ElementAt((dynamic) target, (int) vals[4]);

if (result != null && !((Type) vals[3]).IsAssignableFrom(result.GetType()))
    throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("The retrieved object is a {0}, but the expected type was {1}.", result.GetType(), (Type) vals[3]));

return result;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just need the object from an enumerable, at a given index, here is a simple function that does it:

```
    public static object GetObjectAt(IEnumerable enumerable, int index)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (object obj in enumerable)
        {
            if (i == index)
                return obj;

            i++;
        }
        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
    }
```

And in your case, you would do this:

```
        object oo = GetObjectAt((IEnumerable)(WeakReference)vals[2], (int)vals[4]);
```

Of course there are alternatives that look more sexy (see other answers), with fancy linq queries and cool C# 4 dynamic new trendy stuff :-) but, in general, if you don't "need" the T type (in your example code, you don't need it), you don't need generics. This solution is actually supported with any .NET Framework and C# versions, from 1 to 4.

Comment: Haha best answer for me Simon you made me smile.  This is a good starting point for anyone who wants to know what the "old school" way of doing this is, then you can always build on it with Linq/Lambda etc

Answer (score 1):

I think you're working too hard to be able to use the extension methods which don't seem to be necessary.

```
object[] vals = GetValues();
var list = ((WeakReference)vals[2]).Target as IList;
object oo = null;
if (list != null)
{
    oo = list[(int)vals[4]];
}
```

Comment: `IList<T>` does *not* implement `IList`.

Comment: @Ani - but `List<T>` does implement `IList` so it ought to work regardless of whether the target is a strongly typed list or not.

Comment: Sure, but the OP doesn't say that the `IList<T>` will be a `List<T>`. Btw, I'm not the downvoter.

Comment: @Timwi - so you're suggesting that he's created a special class that implements `IList<T>` but not `IList` since he's trying to cast to `IList<T>` instead of using the generic, built-in list classes?  Seems a little far-fetched to me, but I suppose it's possible. Quoting the docs: `The IList(T) generic interface is a descendant of the ICollection(T) generic interface and is the base interface of all generic lists.`  AFAIK, all the generic lists that implement `IList<T>` also implement `IList`.